# Filter orders in Admin area based on logged in user

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, filters

I have a booking store which uses custom user roles to separate different user types. One of the user types is an 'agent' who makes orders on behalf of end-customers.

[image]

I've successfully set up the admin backend to only show WC -> Orders but I now need to ensure that they can only edit or cancel orders that they themselves have created. I attempted to do this by restricting all posts on the site:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'query_set_only_author' );

function query_set_only_author( $wp_query ) {

 global $current_user;

 if( is_admin() && !current_user_can('edit_others_posts') ) {
    $wp_query->set( 'author', $current_user->ID );
    add_filter('views_edit-post', 'fix_post_counts');
    add_filter('views_upload', 'fix_media_counts');
 }

}
```

This caused all orders to disappear completely from the user's order list. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You might want to check your error log for current_user_can.  That sometimes throws an error.  It should be run after plugins_loaded, or you should be sure to include pluggable.php.  If that isn't the problem, try commenting out the filters, to see if they're having any issues.  Also, [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts#A_Warning_About_Admin_Usage) highly recommends you use $wp->is_main_query && is_post_type_archive('{Your_Post_Type}') for the admin screens.

Comment: Do you think it would be better to scrap current_user_can and use this:
`
$user = wp_get_current_user();
 $roles = ( array ) $user->roles;
 return $roles;
`
Instead?

Comment: If you're already getting documents for which the current user is the author, you shouldn't need to worry about current_user_can.  We refer to that as "security through obscurity".  If they can't see it, they can't edit it.